# Android Image Slider without gallery in a FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create a Tabed application where one tab will hold up to 25-30 images.
I want does images to be able to swipe to the next/prev and not having a gallery.

I've been searching around trying to find some sort of slider example but only found a lot of them using Gallery, witch seems to also be deprecated in ICS and up.

[image: The preferred look]

What I've gotten so far is the actual fragment:

```
public class ImageTab extends Fragment {

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_layout, container, false);
  }

  @Override
  public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
  }

}
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction, it would be mostly appreciated.

best,
Henrik

Comment: see my updated answer, since you are using fragments for your Images I would recommend to do it like that, just ask if implementation is unclear?

Comment: Hmm.. The answer has disappeared from me, I can only see the comment...

Comment: A moderator has deleted the post and it cannot be undeleted. And it was a valid answer to your question, strange...

Comment: for future visitors of this question: this is a great simple example to get start with ViewPager using images. It is simple and basic. Only if you are looking for circle indicators, it does't have them. But you can find many guides on the net on how to add them to it.      http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-viewpager-as-image-slide-gallery-swipe-gallery/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @Hiny: I'm trying to create a Tabed application where one tab will hold up to
>   25-30 images.

Use a FragmentActivity with a tabhost or actionbar tab navigation, where one of the tabs holds a Fragment with a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html).

```
mViewPager.setAdapter(new MyImagesPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
```

> @Hiny: I want does images to be able to swipe to the next/prev and not having
>   a gallery.

The ViewPager will give you this functionality, and it's easy to add a page indicator.

> Quote from the Android Developer site: [Nested Fragments](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments)
>
> "For example, if you use ViewPager to create fragments that swipe left
>   and right and consume a majority of the screen space, you can now
>   insert fragments into each fragment page."

And it's supported from Android 1.6 with the Android Support Library.

> @Hiny: If anyone could point me in the right direction, it would be mostly
>   appreciated.

For code example check out https://github.com/marsucsb/nested-fragments

Comment: Thx, I'll check it out, I just saw your other example earlier today but did not have time to test it, so just saw that it disappeared.